# how to Increase maxjson length for one ajax request

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am making a ajax post call which will pass the viewmodel as a parameter, but now I am getting below error.

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON
>   JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
>   on the maxJsonLength

I saw the suggestion to increase the length through **web.config**, but our team said no for that solution, is there any other solution?

this is my ajax post

```
 $.ajax({
                url: method, //getSvcUrl(method),
                type: "POST",
                data: jsonIn, // ko.toJSON(jsonIn),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
```

is there any way to handle it for one particular post method?

Comment: Show us the MVC code, please.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207539/562424

Comment: @KarthikGanesan mine is post .so i wont able to use it

Comment: $.ajax({
                url: method, //getSvcUrl(method),
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ viewModelList: lstModel, mode: current.mode },
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (json) {
                    callback(json);
                },

Comment: try this then https://stackoverflow.com/a/41172517/562424