# ASP.Net WEB API Failing POST Large JSON data from Mobile

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.net WEB api from Mobile.Its failing every time.I am getting this error.

```
Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
```

I already added maxJsonLength on Webconfig

```
    <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

This is My controller how can i get then JSON inside postDataForSync Method ?
 for now its crashing after constructor method.

```
 public class MobileAPIController : Controller
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer;
    public MobileAPIController() {

        serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

    }


    //
    //GET : MobileAPI/login

    public object login(string userId, string password)
    { 
    }

    //
    //GET : MobileAPI/getDataForSync
    public object getDataForSync(string userId) {

    }

    //
    //POST : MobileAPI/postDataForSync
    [HttpPost]
    public object postDataForSync(string syncData_)
    {
    }
}
```

Error ,

```
[ArgumentException: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
Parameter name: input]
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit) +168
   System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetDeserializedObject(ControllerContext controllerContext) +211
   System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +69
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider() +30
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +105
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass21.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +743
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.&lt;BeginExecuteCore&gt;b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +465
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.&lt;BeginExecute&gt;b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +374
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +384
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +159
</pre>
                        </code>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>
            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3062.0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used my method like this

prev method

```
[HttpPost]
public object postDataForSync(string syncData_)
{
}
```

Updated method

```
[HttpPost]
public object postDataForSync()
{
 Stream req = Request.InputStream;
 req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
 string json = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();
 MyModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json);
}
```

This SO Answer helped me to fix this. - [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41167770/mvc-5-increase-max-json-length-in-post-request/41172517)

Answer (score 1):

have you try add the MaxJsonDeserializerMembers under appsetting on your web config? like this, at least it works for me

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="1500000" />
  </appSettings>
```