# Error during serialization or deserialization using in asp.net webapi POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I was trying to POST  base64 string of 2 image (4MB + in Size) in a object. Here is the Model Sample :

```
public class DemoModel
{
    public string No{ get; set; }
    public string OneBase64 { get; set; }
    public string TwoBase64 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how I am trying to capture POST-ed data in webapi controller.

```
  [HttpPost]
  public string PostSimpleData([FromBody] DemoModel data)
    { 
       // do something 
    }
```

but when I post the json it shows serialization / deserialization error.

[image]

Then I added few lines in webconfig to increase response size & json size.

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>  
         <webServices>                                                   
             <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647" />                 
         </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

and

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

and

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
```

Still no result.
If I post anything except Base64 data It automatically serialize and bind with object in controllers method.

here is the JSON I am trying to POST.

```
{
   "NO" : "01",
   "OneBase64" : "Some base 64 Data",
   "TwoBase64" : "Some base 64 Data"
}
```

any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe that the setting in your web.config applies to WebMethod, but not Web API or MVC. You tagged this as both MVC and Web API - which are you using? You'll need to find a way to adjust the max size for the serializer that your framework is using.

Comment: I am using Web Api 2. can you suggest how should i adjust the max size for serializer ?
I used "<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />" also.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18262484/1139830) solve your issue?

Comment: As an alternative, you can [swap the serializer used by Web API](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/mar/09/using-an-alternate-json-serializer-in-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: @mason I already tried this. I added this line but nop. no luck.

 <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2147483647"/>

Comment: Then I recommend you try swapping out the serializer used by Web API, as I couldn't find any other solution for adjusting that size on the serializer used in Web API by default.

Comment: @KhaledMdTuhidulHossain have you tried to use exact "50000000" value for configurations?

Comment: @svyatis.lviv yes i did. Same issue.

Comment: @mason solved it. Please check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my method from this

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostSimpleData([FromBody] DemoModel data)
{ 
   // do something 
}
```

to this

```
 [HttpPost]
 public string PostSimpleData()
 {
        Stream req = Request.InputStream;
        req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string json = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();
        DemoModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DemoModel>(json);

   //Now i Can Do whatever I want with this data
 }
```

and it worked like a charm. Thanks to this post here [ASP.Net WEB API Failing POST Large JSON data from Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57174250/asp-net-web-api-failing-post-large-json-data-from-mobile/57174895)

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure not your web api but your sender serializer instance directly by applying `serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;` from where are you sending that json object

Comment: I am sending data from android & web (vue js ) application. in android I made a json using GSON .

 Gson gson = new Gson();
  String json = gson.toJson(data);

after this I post the data like this.

 String response = mReq.sendPost(fullUrl,  json,  "application/json");

 can u suggest where should I make the change ?????

Comment: No, this answer does not apply at all. The error is happening on the server when trying to convert the JSON into a .NET object, so changing the settings for the serializer on the client would have no affect.