# how to increase AspNetCore return size

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a project written in aspnetcore 3.0

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IList<DataType>> GetAsync(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    var data = await _query.GetAsync(startTime, endTime);
    return data;
}
```

1. when "data" has few thousands records, everything is fine, I get the data on front end.
2. when "data" has about 1 million records, I got an empty response back on front end, status = 200, data = ""

Anyone know how to increase the response size?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify the default allowed response size settings for a Web API Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436533/how-to-modify-the-default-allowed-response-size-settings-for-a-web-api-applicati)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Kestrel then try change [MaxResponseBufferSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

```
.UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.Limits.MaxResponseBufferSize = 52428800; //50MB
                });
```

I don't have that much of data to test this.