# Return a model containing stream in ASP MVC4 Webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, stream, asp.net-web-api

My model class looks like this

```
public Stream FileStream { get; set; }
public string FileName { get; set; }
public string ContentType { get; set; }
```

Is it possible to return this model to webapi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Stream is just a pointer to some actual resource. If you want to send this to the response and be able to serialize it you could use a byte array.

Or event better, write the Stream to the response and then use standard HTTP headers for the 2 other properties:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report.pdf

... the actual content comes here
```

You could also consider writing a custom [`MediaTypeFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.mediatypeformatter%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to achieve this as shown in [`this article`](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/creating-custom-csvmediatypeformatter-in-asp-net-web-api-for-comma-separated-values-csv-format).

Answer (score 0):

No. This cannot be automatically serialised. But returning a stream is easy. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api).