# stream to zip using DotNetZip

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, stream, dotnetzip

I have a Stream that i want to read and then zip it,

This stream is generated by **HttpRequestMessage** in web api  as posting a zip file through restclient and code as below

```
var task = this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            task.Wait();    
                           using (Stream requestStream = task.Result)
                {  }
```

using DotNetZip i need to convert this requeststream to zip file ?

Waiting for your comments

Comment: what is the question here exactly? you already have the stream and all you need is to check the capability of DotNetZip to see if it accepts a stream directly and creates a zip file out of it. BTW, you can use async-await to improve your code `await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();`

Comment: @KiranChallan i have uploaded a zip file in rest client i need to download as such in through above code

Comment: Have you looked at the following post? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9549889/1184056

Comment: @KiranChalla not yet will check and update u

Comment: @KiranChalla have this works for zip file