# File download via MVC web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have several questions:

1. Can I use web api for file download? How? Sample?
2. How do I test that webapi call is working?
3. How do I call that api from after clicking a link? I don't want to open up a new page only for download.

Comment: have you looked at other answers on this site? Like this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/9549889/333082

Comment: It seems like that it does not work. I am putting the address in browser and it is throwing a 500 exception. How do I test if it is working?

Comment: I'd try to figure the details of the exception first and see if you can resolve that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning binary file from controller in ASP.NET Web API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api)