# When to use HttpResponseMessage and Request.CreateResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

When should we use the `HttpResponseMessage` object and when should we use the `Request.CreateResponse(...)` method?

Also, what is the difference between the `HttpResponseMessage` object and the `Request.CreateResponse(...)` method?

Comment: `CreateResponse()` and `CreateErrorResponse()` are just helpers (extension methods) to make developers' life easier.

Comment: @abatishchev: I think there is also a different, that is `CreateResponse` (and probably `CreateErrorResponse`) will use current request headers for response But `HttpResponseMessage` create New response and headers, thats true?

Comment: You can explore it from source code: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> What is difference between HttpResponseMessage object and
>   Request.CreateResponse(...) method?

It is probably obvious but `Request.CreateResponse` is a helper method for creating `HttpResponseMessage` object.

> When we must use HttpResponseMessage object and When we must use
>   Request.CreateResponse(...) method?

If you want to use the built-in content negotiation feature, use `Request.CreateResponse`. When you return an object, ASP.NET Web API has to serialize the object into response body. This could be generally JSON or XML (other media types are possible but you need to create the formatter). The media type chosen (JSON or XML) is based on the request content type, `Accept` header in the request and so on and content negotiation is the process that determines the media type to be used. By using `Request.CreateResponse`, you are automatically using the result of this process.

On the other hand, if you create `HttpResponseMessage` yourself, you have to specify a media formatter based on which the object will be serialized and by specifying the media formatter yourself, you can override the results of conneg.

EDIT
Here is an example of how to specify JSON formatter.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    var foo = new Foo() { Id = id };
    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new ObjectContent<Foo>(foo,
                  Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter)
    };
}
```

With this, even if you send a request with `Accept:application/xml`, you will only get JSON.

Comment: How i can specify a media formatter based on which the object will be serialized in `HttpResponseMessage` ? please give a example

Comment: @user197508 you don't have to specify because it will happen automatically by the CreateResponse - detail you can read here http://imcodebased.com/setting-httpcontext-response-using-httpresponsemessage-or-request-createresponse-in-webapi2/

Answer (score 4):

Request.CreateResponse(...) is just a builder, it also returns instance of HttpResponseMessage, here is the code:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage CreateResponse<T>(this HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, T value, HttpConfiguration configuration)
{
  if (request == null)
    throw Error.ArgumentNull("request");
  configuration = configuration ?? HttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetConfiguration(request);
  if (configuration == null)
    throw Error.InvalidOperation(SRResources.HttpRequestMessageExtensions_NoConfiguration, new object[0]);
  IContentNegotiator contentNegotiator = ServicesExtensions.GetContentNegotiator(configuration.Services);
  if (contentNegotiator == null)
  {
    throw Error.InvalidOperation(SRResources.HttpRequestMessageExtensions_NoContentNegotiator, new object[1]
    {
      (object) typeof (IContentNegotiator).FullName
    });
  }
  else
  {
    IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters = (IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter>) configuration.Formatters;
    ContentNegotiationResult negotiationResult = contentNegotiator.Negotiate(typeof (T), request, formatters);
    if (negotiationResult == null)
    {
      return new HttpResponseMessage()
      {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable,
        RequestMessage = request
      };
    }
    else
    {
      MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType = negotiationResult.MediaType;
      return new HttpResponseMessage()
      {
        Content = (HttpContent) new ObjectContent<T>(value, negotiationResult.Formatter, mediaType),
        StatusCode = statusCode,
        RequestMessage = request
      };
    }
  }
```