# Return JSON as a result in Wcf Services

Tags: c#, json, oracle, wcf

I am creating the wcf service, to query the Oracle Database and return result in JSON format.How to convert the result from the Oracle query in to JSON message

```
 public class Service1 : IService1
 {
  public HttpResponseMessage GetData(string ROOM)
{
     List<OracleParameter> prms = new List<OracleParameter>();
    prms.Add(new OracleParameter("ROOM", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ROOM, ParameterDirection.Input));
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TGSDataBaseConnection"].ConnectionString;            using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
    {
        DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
        var strQuery = "SELECT * from LIMS_SAMPLE_RESULTS_VW where ROOM = :ROOM";
        var returnObject = new { data = new OracleDataTableJsonResponse(connStr, strQuery, prms.ToArray()) };
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
        ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
        if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=TGSData.json", out contentDisposition))
        {
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
        }
        return response;
    }
```

It throws error like The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context in the line

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
```

I added the

```
 using System.Net.Http;
 using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
 using System.Net.Http.Headers;
```

And added their assemblies as reference. But still showing the same error. 
[image]

Comment: what is response ?

Comment: @viveknuna response is what we get from the Oracle Database

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `Request`to `HttpContext.Current.Request`

Comment: `Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Web.HttpRequest' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' 
Argument 4: cannot convert from 'System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue' to 'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration'
'System.Web.HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'CreateResponse' and the best extension method overload 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse<T>(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage, System.Net.HttpStatusCode, T, System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: These are the error messages. Also added the screenshot I added in the question

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22066963/3272054 so instead of a HttpRequest you should try HttpRequestMessageExtensions.