# CA2000 Warning in my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, dispose

I am working on a Web API for a SPA app.  I am trying to figure out how to get rid of the CA2000 warning in one of my controllers. The below code generates a CA2000 warning-

```
    [Route("Execution/TestCaseOrExecutionExcelExport")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetTestCaseOrExecutionExcelExport([FromBody] dynamic data)
    {
            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        using (result)
        {
            ...
            result.Headers.AcceptRanges.Add("bytes");
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = filename };
        }
            return result;
    }
```

If I change the above as follows, I get "Not all paths return a value" error, since the function returns HttpResponseMessage-

```
    [Route("Execution/TestCaseOrExecutionExcelExport")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetTestCaseOrExecutionExcelExport([FromBody] dynamic data)
    {
  using (HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK))
        {    
             ...
             return result;
        }
     }
```

One other note, the below code gives the error "Cannot access a disposed object." but does get rid of the ca2000 warning-

```
   [Route("Execution/TestCaseOrExecutionExcelExport")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetTestCaseOrExecutionExcelExport([FromBody] dynamic data)
    {
        using (result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK))
        {
    ...
    }
    return result;
}
```

Trying things without much luck.

How can I code this to get rid of the CA2000 warning?

**UPDATE:  Fixed the issue, just not sure why what I did solved my issues.  The only thing I did was to move the HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK); line outside of the method at the class level.  Why would the object be disposed of at the class level and not within the method?

Comment: With it at a class level, you should be getting CA2213, but there's a limitation apparently in that CA2213 does not work so well if you have a disposable base class. See this question someone else asked today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032088/difference-between-class-level-variable-and-method-for-ca2000-warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Request.CreateResponse instead of using the constructor for new HttpResponseMessage. See this accepted answer for some reasons: [When Use HttpResponseMessage and Request.CreateResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060357/when-use-httpresponsemessage-and-request-createresponse)

I've never seen CA2000 when using this approach.

Comment: You are right, it does not produce CA2000 warnings.  How would I add the custom hears changes (some appear in my example)?

Comment: you still assign Request.CreateResponse(...) to a variable and then you should be able to do almost anything you need to that variable. Mostly, you're just changing the one line with `new` and then removing the `using`  line and curly braces. Keep what's still inside those curly braces and you should be good.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!