# String too large for FormUrlEncodedContent() in Windows Phone 8 Post upload

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, http-post

My code:

```
string json = BuildJson(uploadItem);

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("parameter", json));

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(App.Current.LoginUrl, content);

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

My json string includes an base64 encoded image so the `FormUrlEncodedContent` throws the exception :

> " Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long".

Important is that the server expects exact this format with "parameter" as post key and the json as the post value. How can I bypass this limitation of `FormUrlEncodedContent`?

Comment: Have you looked at what is being transmitted over the wire with a debugger, such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com)?

Comment: There is not anything being transmitted because the exception is thrown before

Comment: So what Uri does the debugger tell you is being passed to `PostAsync`?

Comment: The URI is ok because with a shorter string all works fine. Only with a large base64 string from an image the exception is thrown

Comment: Where does it throw the exception?

Comment: as i mentioned in my post, in "FormUrlEncodedContent" method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set large string inside HttpContent when using HttpClient?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703735/how-to-set-large-string-inside-httpcontent-when-using-httpclient)

Comment: You can't do it.  So you have to do something else.  What are the possibilities of doing it differently?

Comment: Thanks to all, [this post solved my problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695208/uri-escapedatastring-invalid-uri-the-uri-string-is-too-long/10755250#10755250)

Comment: Hi ManzMoody, May i know how you fix this issue. I'm stuck in the ditto same issue.

Comment: I just posted my solution, hope it helps ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with the following method which replaces FormUrlEncodedContent :

```
// URI Escape JSON string
var content = EscapeDataString(json);

private string EscapeDataString(string str)
{
    int limit = 2000;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int loops = str.Length / limit;

    for (int i = 0; i <= loops; i++)
    {
        if (i < loops)
        {
            sb.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(str.Substring(limit * i, limit)));
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(str.Substring(limit * i)));
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Does not work with the HttpClient - Assembly System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0,