# How to pass long string in HttpClient.PostAsync request

Tags: c#, http-post, httpclient

Trying to send a rather long string to a REST web api (youtrack). I get the following exception:

Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.

My code:

```
var encodedMessage = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message);
var requestUri = string.Format("{0}{1}issue/{2}/execute?comment={3}", url, YoutrackRestUrl, issue.Id, encodedMessage);
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, null).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

So I took my chances with a `FormUrlEncodedContent`

```
var requestUri = string.Format("{0}{1}issue/{2}/execute", url, YoutrackRestUrl, issue.Id);

var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("comment", message));

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Which results in the exact same issue.

The string (comment) I am sending, is the changed file set of a commit into SVN. Which can be really long, so I don't really have a way to get around that. Is there a way to post content without the string length restriction?

Read the following topics, but didn't find an answer there:

- [.NET HttpClient. How to POST string value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176538/net-httpclient-how-to-post-string-value)
- [How do I set up HttpContent for my HttpClient PostAsync second parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971510/how-do-i-set-up-httpcontent-for-my-httpclient-postasync-second-parameter)
- https://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/how-to-call-httpclient-postasync-with-a-query-string/
- http://forums.asp.net/t/2057125.aspx?Invalid+URI+The+Uri+string+is+too+long+HttpClient

Comment: is the behaviour the same if You're only posting like 1 character in your message ?

Comment: It might be that you Youtrack api has a limmit on the 'comment' field. What does their API documentation say about that ? if there's a restriction on the comment property/field - then - not much You can do about it except than shorten it...

Comment: according to their docs: no limit. the exception occurs on the line "var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);"

Comment: @Marty works fine with 1 char, or 2000 for that matter. only goes wrong for 65000+ messages

Comment: Could it be an issue with `FormUrlEncodedContent` class? Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23740338/189738

Comment: can You post an full Http request that is being sent to the server ? with headers, urls ect.. You can easily capture it with Fiddler

Comment: @Marty, no need. Copy/pasted the `MyFormUrlEncodedContent` and it works like a charm. Many thx. Either drop it as answer, or I will look at your other answers and make sure you are properly rewarded for you help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the short answer to it - just put it into the Body, instead of trying to push all the data via the URL

But as the work on the ticket showed - the answer was here [How to set large string inside HttpContent when using HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703735/how-to-set-large-string-inside-httpcontent-when-using-httpclient/23740338#23740338)

The actual problem beeing in the `FormUrlEncodedContent`

Comment: That is what second example does, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..Will be helpful for uwp..

```
 Uri uri = new Uri("your uri string");
 Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
 var value1 = new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>>
 { 
     // your key value pairs
 };

 var response = await client.PostAsync(uri,new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(value1));
 var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: i am doing this keyvalue things... but still uri is still too long...