# Path Too Long Exception(Uri) in Uwp

Tags: uwp

Currently trying to upload image to database through uri. for that i am using HttpClient class. But it shows path too long exception.(because i convert the image to base64 string and upload it). I tried to insert through WebClient class but unfortunately WebClient class is not available in uwp. so how do i upload the image through uri??

Code

```
    public async void Upload()
    {

        var url1 = "http://www.example.com/upload.php";
        var values1 = new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>
        {

             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Date", x.Date.ToString()),
             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Bill_Image", x.Bill_Image.ToString()),

         };
             HttpClient client1 = new HttpClient();
             HttpResponseMessage response1 = new HttpResponseMessage();

             try
             {
                response1 = await client1.PostAsync(url1,new FormUrlEncodedContent(values1));

                    if (response1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var dialog = new MessageDialog("Successfully Added");
                        await dialog.ShowAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // problems handling here
                    }
              }
              catch (Exception exc)
              {
                  Debug.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
              }
      }
```

Comment: The PostAsync call looks OK. Which line exactly do you get the exception?

Comment: In the PostAsync line itself.. "response1 = await client1.PostAsync(url1,new FormUrlEncodedContent(values1));"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass long string in HttpClient.PostAsync request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047048/how-to-pass-long-string-in-httpclient-postasync-request)

Comment: It seems that `FormUrlEncodedContent` has constants limiting the size of request length. Instead, you can try to use `StringContent` It actually is HttpContent.

Comment: i tried to do with your references. but it seems to be working.. but the database row value is empty..why so??

Comment: @Manikandan You could use fildder to capture data in your client and server. If your server get data successfully. I’m afraid this issue was due to your database.

Comment: okay.. let me try.. i have json object in c#. How do i capture this json object in php file?? have any idea regarding that??

Comment: @Manikandan Please check [Fiddler document](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureFiddler) to learn how to use it.

Comment: Found the solution.. Used the Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient. And  used HttpFormUrlEncodedContent instead of  FormUrlEncodedContent.. And that got successfully inserted.