# FormUrlEncodedContent works but StringContent does not

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I have a question about those 2 httpcontents.

I've made an webapi (php), copy from this: http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/create-restful-services-api-in-php.html
I re-used the Rest.inc.php, and implement my own api file.

I try to call this api from .Net (I'm a .Net developer) - a simple WinForm Application - the FormUrlEncodedContent works but the StringContent does not.
This my code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters.Add("username", username);
        parameters.Add("title", title);
        parameters.Add("text", text);
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);
        var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/json");
        //var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
        PostData(url, content);
```

And the reason why I want to use StringContent: in the real data, sometime the parameters will contain a byte[] (photo), and the FormUrlEncodedContent can't handle it

Please help me
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

They are very different formats. If the api does not have a smart model binder like Asp.Net Web API then it will not work. You can always base64 encode your byte array which is the typical way to transmit bytes via HTTP.

Comment: Can you make it more clearly... 
In my case, the FormUrlEncodedContent has worked, but if I use an encodetring from a byte[], it said the uir is too long
Here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703735/how-to-set-large-string-inside-httpcontent-when-using-httpclient
So I change to StringContent, as that post said...

Comment: Do you want to use JSON or Form Encoding? Either way you will have to change your PHP service.

Comment: I think json is ok ~~
About the php service, how can I change it? I'm not a php developer, just try to find a solution for my case...

Comment: @haiduong87 I'm not a PHP dev either, but I'm sure there are libraries for working with JSON.

Comment: I've tried restsharp
It's ok now
But still don't know how it works :)