# How to get rid of exceed length of query string in my POST request?

Tags: c#, post, uwp

Use to send the base64 image to the server, and sometimes face the problem of exceeding the maximum line length. How it can be avoided?

[image]

Code of my POST:

```
 var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
       {
        { "kod", "111" },
        { "id_user", user.Id },
        { "image", encodedFile },
        { "title", "MyText" },
        { "text", "1234526" }
       };

        var content = new System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://MyUri/tape.php", content);

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

---

Full code of my request:

```
private async void Send_File_But(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker open = new FileOpenPicker();
        open.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        open.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

        // Filter to include a sample subset of file types
        open.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

        // Open a stream for the selected file
        StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync();

        var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        var bytes = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);

        string encodedFile = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);



        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
       {
        { "kod", "111" },
        { "id_user", user.Id },
        { "image", encodedFile },
        { "title", "MyText" },
        { "text", "1234526" }
       };

        var content = new System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://MyUri/tape.php", content);

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


    }
```

Comment: What's generating the error? Is your content *actually* being sent in the body of the request, as I'd expect? (If so, I wouldn't expect there to be any limits.)

Comment: This error generating when i choose big image.

Comment: That doesn't say *what's* generating the error. Is it in PHP, is it on the client side? You mention the query string in your title - are you suggesting this *is* posting to a long URL?

Comment: @JonSkeet Clint side. This error appears when "encodedFile" - so long string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set large string inside HttpContent when using HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703735/how-to-set-large-string-inside-httpcontent-when-using-httpclient)

Comment: So how does it "appear"? Fundamentally you've not given us information.