# How to put a file in the HttpResponseMessage Content?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I want to return a file in an HttpResponseMessage Content something like this:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, {{a file here}});
```

Or this:

```
return new HttpResponseMessage() {
   StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK; 
   Content = {{ a file "example.zip" here}}
};
```

Is this possible?

Comment: See the following post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api. That should probably give you some hints on how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the System.Net.Http.HttpContent.StreamContent instance to add a FileStream object to the to the HttpResponseMessage's Content property.  Something like this:

```
        // Return archive stream
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") {
            FileName = fileName.ToString()
        };
```

Note that you should probably also add a MD5 checksum to the file content in real applications.

Comment: Hello, On the client side, how do get the filestream from the responsemessage?? Any idea?