# Custom Azure API Apps for Files

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, swagger, .net-4.6, azure-logic-apps

I'm looking to create some custom API apps for the sole purpose of creating a/some Logic Apps. With these custom API Apps, I want to pass around files. These files will usually be CSV, ZIP, Excel, TXT, and some other formats - unknown to the consumer until the file is returned (i.e. the client does not dictate the file format).

How does one do something like this in a way that's compatible with Swagger/Swashbuckle, Web API, and Logic Apps? I'll ultimately be tying this into an FTP connector, Dropbox, Onebox, or other file-storage connector.

Does following something [like this work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api) or do I need to take a different approach? For example, should I simply work with JSON objects and let my binary be base64-encoded by using a model like this?

```
public class BinaryFile
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
    public string DeducedMimeType { get; set; }
    public int FileSize { get; set; }
    public string FileEncoding { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileBinary { get; set; }
}
```

([this question is cross-posted to MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d515b609-f839-4ca4-8de1-3e9e680622f2/custom-api-apps-for-files?forum=azurelogicapps))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I've taken is what I posed in the question with the `BinaryFile` class. I've broken it out into a few classes. I'm not done - I have some improvements to make still but this is functional right now.

Main class with some common fields:

```
public class FileResult<T>
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public T File { get; set; }
    public IList<string> ErrorMessages { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public bool IsSuccessful { get; set; } = false;
}
```

This is the `<T>` in my `FileResult<T>` class:

```
public class CsvFile
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string Contents { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}

public class BinaryFile
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
    public string DeducedMimeType { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public byte[] Contents { get; set; }
}
```

Note that in my case, there are some times when I am working with multiple files and not just one, so what could appear to be some common fields are still within the type passed in as the `<T>` so I can have something like `FileResult<IEnumerable<CsvFile>>`.

This is all playing nicely with Swagger, Swashbuckle, Web API, Azure API Apps, and Azure Logic Apps. For the cases where I am returning multiple files to my Azure Logic App, I use the fairly hidden `splitsOn` feature (that also has some designer bugs, so be careful!) to easily iterate over all of the files. It works very nicely.