# How to return file from ASP.net 5 web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, postman

Created wep api in asp.net 5. I am tring to return file response for Post request. But instead of file the response looks like 
`

```
{
  "version": {
    "major": 1,
    "minor": 1,
    "build": -1,
    "revision": -1,
    "majorRevision": -1,
    "minorRevision": -1
  },
  "content": {
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Content-Disposition",
        "value": [
          "attachment; filename=test.pdf"
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "Content-Type",
        "value": [
          "application/pdf"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "statusCode": 200,
  "reasonPhrase": "OK",
  "headers": [],
  "requestMessage": null,
  "isSuccessStatusCode": true
}`
```

Code:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]DocumentViewModel vm)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var Document = _repository.GetDocumentByGuid(vm.DocumentGuid, User.Identity.Name);
                var Params = Helper.ClientInputToRealValues(vm.Parameters, Document.DataFields);
                var file = Helper.GeneratePdf(Helper.InsertValues(Params, Document.Content));                 

                var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Content = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file))
                };
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = "test.pdf"
                };
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
                return result;

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return null;
        }
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return null;

    }
```

How can I return the real file as the response instead of JSON ?I am using Postman as test client.

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api

Comment: nop, it still returns json as result:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

used IActionResult instead of HttpResponseMessage. And returned FileStreamResult, and got it working.

Got a new problem, the file is not the one I open with the stream from server. But will create a new question for that.

Continues : [Return file from ASP.NET 5 Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856983/asp-net-5-web-api-return-file-as-response)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is the "low-level" HTTP approach, which should work with both ASP.NET WebAPI or ASP.NET MVC.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Download()
{
  var fs = new FileStream(myfileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 32768, true);
  var response = new HttpResponseMessage {
    Content = new StreamContent(fs);
  }
  response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
  response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
  return response;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `fs.Dispose()` close the file before WebAPI has a chance to use the file stream? If not, then how does `Dispose()` work in this scenario?

Comment: To answer my question above: You do not need to (and probably shouldn't) call `Dispose` on the stream you pass to `StreamContent`. I will edit your answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788127/2279059

Comment: It's still not WebAPI, because `this.Request.CreateResponse` does not exist in a WebAPI controller.

Answer (score 2):

Does setting `HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"` help at all?

This should fit your needs:

```
public FileResult TestDownload()
    {
        HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("YOUR PATH TO PDF"), "application/pdf")
        {
            FileDownloadName = "test.pdf"
        };

        return result;                                
    }
```

Comment: Does `"headers": [],` have anything populated now? As I can see from your initial post that it's empty. What build of asp.net 5 are you using, and is it full .net or coreclr?

Comment: Nope, it remains empty.

Comment: Full - dnx451 ,build rc1-final

Comment: If I add the header manually to HttpResponseMessage like that:
result.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
it throws : "Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects."