# Download large zip file using web Api and angular 2

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc

**Get Web-API method to download zip file**

**This code is not working**

Please help me out on this.

```
public HttpResponseMessage SampleDownload()
            {
                try {
                    HttpResponseMessage result = null;
                    var path = @"D:\sample\sample.zip";
                    var filename = "sample.zip";
                    if (File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
                        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
                        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = filename;
                    }
                    return result;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps include what error or output you are receiving, to give some insight into why the code is failing? :)

Comment: Thanks Flauntster , I got the code working.but with a different approach. Reference: " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383338/how-to-download-a-zipfile-from-a-dotnet-core-webapi ". Did some modification for client-side.

Comment: @trinetra: Post what you did to solve the issue as answer and then accept it when you can. That way this question doesn't remain perpetually in the "unanswered" status.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks for reminding. Will do it tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

**C# Web API Code:**

```
public IActionResult GetZipFile(string filename)
{
    // It can be zip file or pdf but we need to change contentType respectively
    const string contentType ="application/zip";
    HttpContext.Response.ContentType = contentType;
    var result = new FileContentResult(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"{path_to_files}\file.zip"), contentType)
    {
         // It can be zip file or pdf but we need to change the extension respectively
        FileDownloadName = $"{filename}.zip"
    };

    return result;
}
```

**Angular Code:**

**Requirement: FileSaver ( Install file saver package)**

**import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';**

```
 this.http.get(url,{ responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }).subscribe((response)=>{
             var blob = new Blob([response['_body']], {type: "application/zip"});
              FileSaver.saveAs(blob,dlData.file_name);
        }).catch((error) => {
           // Error code
        });
```

**Reference url :  [How to download a ZipFile from a dotnet core webapi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383338/how-to-download-a-zipfile-from-a-dotnet-core-webapi)**