# Cannot access closed file System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, idisposable

I am trying to read and return a file content from WebAPI Rest Service, I am returning the response inside the using.. block. I am getting System.ObjectDisposedException.  Can someone help me with this?

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(LocalFilePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "MaxRecords.xls" };
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                return response;
            }
```

Comment: Don't use "using" block then?

Comment: Does it work If you remove the using block? `response.Content` is referencing an instance that is disposed (`fileStream`).

Comment: @DaveBecker Yes, it works after removing using block.. But I wanted to have using block to dispose the filestream :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly dispose the stream when using StreamContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784434/how-to-properly-dispose-the-stream-when-using-streamcontent)

Comment: Not directly relevant, but are you creating a real Excel file or faking it by returning a CSV or HTML file with an `xls` extension? This is guaranteed to lead to client issues. `xls` is obsolete for the past 10 years. You can create a real XLSX file *very* easily with a library like EPPlus, without fake content or installing Excel on the server

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a stream pushing object that produces bits of file onto the wire as needed. I've built one myself, but I understand there's one in the box these days - called [PushStreamContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.pushstreamcontent(v=vs.118).aspx). Here's a pretty simple example that [does something similar](https://weblogs.asp.net/andresv/asynchronous-streaming-in-asp-net-webapi) to what you need.

The issue is, either the client needs to close the stream, or the `PushStreamContent` needs to close it when all bytes have been written, but with the `using` block, you're closing it immediately when you send.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the using block. It isn't needed. `StreamContent` will `Dispose` it for you.

See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/cffe60fcec1f85f755f41562b0c207700fdbc043/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/StreamContent.cs .