# Return file in ASP.Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

### Problem

I want to return a file in my ASP.Net Web API Controller, but all my approaches return the `HttpResponseMessage` as JSON.

### Code so far

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadAsync(string id)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StreamContent({{__insert_stream_here__}});
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    return response;
}
```

When I call this endpoint in my browser, the Web API returns the `HttpResponseMessage` as JSON with the HTTP Content Header set to `application/json`.

Comment: For .NET 6 you can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75832332/16877062).

Answer (score 365, accepted):

If this is ASP.net-Core then you are mixing web API versions. Have the action return a derived `IActionResult` because in your current code the framework is treating `HttpResponseMessage` as a model.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DownloadController : Controller {
    //GET api/download/12345abc
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string id) {
        Stream stream = await {{__get_stream_based_on_id_here__}}

        if(stream == null)
            return NotFound(); // returns a NotFoundResult with Status404NotFound response.

        return File(stream, "application/octet-stream", "{{filename.ext}}"); // returns a FileStreamResult
    }    
}
```

Note:

> The framework will dispose of the stream used in this case when the response is completed. If a `using` statement is used, the stream will be disposed before the response has been sent and result in an exception or corrupt response.

Comment: In my case I needed to render an Excel in memory and return it for download, so I needed to define a file name with extension as well: `return File(stream, "application/octet-stream", "filename.xlsx");`

This way when it downloads the user can open it directly.

Comment: I understand what the `NotFound()` ultimately does, but does it reside in .NET Core or is it something local to your project?

Comment: @ΩmegaMan it is a helper method on `ControllerBase` and is part of the framework itself https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.notfound?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Ok, found *my* issue, though my controller was working in .NET Core 2.2, it was not derived from the base class `Controller` an thus didn't have access to the `ControllerBase.NotFound()` method. Once derived, it all worked. lol / thx

Comment: @Nkosi any way to transfer obtain file from url and stream it to client in chunks as we get from source? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62476452/download-large-file-from-url-in-net-core-web-api

Comment: @user1066231 have a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-2.0?view=aspnetcore-3.1#enhanced-http-header-support focus on range header

Comment: Do you not need a using statement here?

Comment: @RobL not in this case. the framework will dispose of the stream when the response is completed. If you use a `using` statement the stream will be disposed before the response has been sent.

Comment: @RobL check the source code that actually writes the stream to the response. Note the `using` statement applied to the passed in stream https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Infrastructure/FileResultExecutorBase.cs,398

Comment: Won't even compile because it can't convert the File(...) to Task<IActionResult>.

Comment: @CoderSteve did you await anything in the action?

Comment: @CoderSteve if you look at the [source code](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs,1104) You will see that `File` does return an `IActionResult` derived object.

Comment: The magic behind `__get_stream_based_on_id_here__` could be interesting since common functions that return a Stream of a file are not async whereas functions that are async are only returning a byte array etc. Ofc, I could create another Stream from  the byte array but I was wondering if there is a solution with one Stream only.

Comment: Thank you @Nkosi, your comment saved my sanity! I was getting a 500 server error when returning a `File(...)`. I had the memoryStream incorrectly wrapped in a using statement.

Comment: @KevinBrydon I am glad it helped. Happy Coding.

Comment: If someone trying in postman then you can also convert from stream to byte[] and then return byte[] in the return File(byte[]., mimetype) parameter

Comment: @KurtisJungersen You do not know how many lives you are saving with your comment!! I get it working for me only after giving the file name. Thanks to you!

Answer (score 57):

You can return FileResult with this methods:

> 1: Return FileStreamResult

```
    [HttpGet("get-file-stream/{id}"]
    public async Task<FileStreamResult> DownloadAsync(string id)
    {
        var fileName="myfileName.txt";
        var mimeType="application/...."; 
        Stream stream = await GetFileStreamById(id);

        return new FileStreamResult(stream, mimeType)
        {
            FileDownloadName = fileName
        };
    }
```

> 2: Return FileContentResult

```
    [HttpGet("get-file-content/{id}"]
    public async Task<FileContentResult> DownloadAsync(string id)
    {
        var fileName="myfileName.txt";
        var mimeType="application/...."; 
        byte[] fileBytes = await GetFileBytesById(id);

        return new FileContentResult(fileBytes, mimeType)
        {
            FileDownloadName = fileName
        };
    }
```

Comment: If within a `ControllerBase` there are many overloaded versions of [`ControllerBase.File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-2.2) helper that returns any one of those.

Comment: Your answer is still valid. So do not feel disheartened. I was just pointing out some resources you can use to support your answer.

Comment: Yes this is true.

Comment: using `FileStreamResult` will help you keep the server memory consumption under control. Since you are not bringing the entire large file in memory, rather streaming it.

Answer (score 40):

Here is a simplistic example of streaming a file:

```cs
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<FileStreamResult> Download(int id)
{
    var path = "<Get the file path using the ID>";
    var stream = File.OpenRead(path);
    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

Note:

Be sure to use `FileStreamResult` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` and **not** from `System.Web.Mvc`.

Answer (score 8):

**ASP.NET 5 WEB API & Angular 12**

You can return a FileContentResult object (Blob) from the server. It'll not get automatically downloaded. You may create an anchor tag in your front-end app programmatically and set the href property to an object URL created from the Blob by the method below. Now clicking on the anchor will download the file. You can set a file name by setting the 'download' attribute to the anchor as well.

```
downloadFile(path: string): Observable<any> {
        return this._httpClient.post(`${environment.ApiRoot}/accountVerification/downloadFile`, { path: path }, {
            observe: 'response',
            responseType: 'blob'
        });
    }

saveFile(path: string, fileName: string): void {
            this._accountApprovalsService.downloadFile(path).pipe(
                take(1)
            ).subscribe((resp) => {
                let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
                downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(resp.body);
                downloadLink.setAttribute('download', fileName);
                document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                downloadLink.click();
                downloadLink.remove();
            });
            
        }
```

**Backend**

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "SystemAdmin, SystemUser")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(FilePath model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(model.Path);
            var content = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(model.Path);
            new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider()
                .TryGetContentType(fileName, out string contentType);
            return File(content, contentType, fileName);
        }
        catch
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }

    return BadRequest();

}
```

Comment: why would you pass a filepath from the frontend to the backend

Comment: Assume there is a page that lists uploaded user documents by file name, each list item(document) has a download button, the backend is WEB API.

Comment: you would pass a name not a path: path to upload, name or id to download

Comment: yeah, Id is the recommended field to pass. That code wasnt refactored.

Comment: Thanks. I know some questions accepted, but i use .net 7.0 only work with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Following is the basic example of returning file (e.g Image file) in .NET Core Web API:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("RenderImage", new { id = id})" alt="No Image found" />
```

Below is the code for returning File from controller to view. Following is Action method which will return file:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DownloadController : Controller
    {
        //GET api/download/123
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RenderImage(string userId)
        {
            //get Image file using _fileservice from db
            var result = await _fileService.getFile(userId);

            if (result.byteStream == null)
                return NotFound();

            return File(result.byteStream, result.ContentType, result.FileName);
        }
    }
```

Note:

> Our file should be first converted into byte[] and then saved in database as varbinary(max) in order to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

add
builder.Services.AddSingleton();
in
Program.cs

```
    [HttpGet("{fileId}")]
    public ActionResult GetFile(string fileId)
    {
        string pathToFile = "test.rar";
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathToFile))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if(!_fileExtensionContentTypeProvider.TryGetContentType(pathToFile,
            out var ContentType))
        {
            ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        }
        var byets=System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathToFile);
        return File(byets, ContentType, Path.GetFileName(pathToFile));
    }
}
```