# Return Download File in ASP.NET Core API from Axios Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, axios

Good day guys,

I'm trying to download file from ASP.NET Core Web API from Axios Request.

Here's my sample API method. (Code based from this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460198/return-file-in-asp-net-core-web-api))

```
[HttpPost("download")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(){
    ...
    return File(new MemoryStream(mypdfbyte), "application/octet-stream", "myfile.pdf");
}
```

Here's my sample axios request.

```
axios.post(`api/products/download`).then(response=>{
    console.log(response.data)
}).catch(error=>{ console.log(error) })
```

But I'm only receiving this. No download file appears.

[image]

I hope you can help me download a file from my controller api.

Comment: 1) `File` takes a `byte[]`. Wrapping your `byte[]` in a `MemoryStream` is pointless, and only serves to double the memory utilization. 2) If the file is a PDF, why aren't you returning it with a PDF mimetype? (`application/pdf`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, DownloadFile should be HttpGet instead of HttpPost. 
Then your axios request should look like

```
axios({
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/products/download',
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'blob', // important
}).then((response) => {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
});
```

Comment: it works perfectly fine with `post` too sir. Thank you sir. It works now :)

Comment: @AppleCiderYummy That's not the point. It should be a get request because of how the REST specification defines what get and post requests do. Although its technically possible to perform any action with any verb, Get requests read data from the server. Post requests are used to create new resources on the server. By using a post to perform what should be a get, its like using the wrong word for something in English and still having the person understand what you're trying to say. Plus its more difficult to reason about the code later.

Comment: this code is working for downloading txt & pdf files but its not working for downloading png & xlsx file. how to handle those filetype?

Comment: Doesn’t using a get or post depend on whether you are sending data too? You could try to send data to a pdf generator and you might not want to send query string parameters, preferring to use request body? So you might choose to use a post action for what is effectively a get.

Answer (score 0):

Here is :

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public FileContentResult Download()
    { 
    ... 
    return File("thisFile"); 
    }
```