# HttpResponseMessage from .NET Web API doesn't have ByteArray

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, epplus

I'm trying to get an excel from the api, but eventhough I am setting it on the controller side, when it comes to the angular side, response doesn't have any content in it but headers.

This is how I'm setting the `HttpResponseMessage` on the Controller side:

```
HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
using (package)
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("LIST of FILES");
    worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(files);

    httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(package.GetAsByteArray());
    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "EXCEL - "+ DateTime.Now.ToString();
    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers
        .MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
}

return httpResponseMessage;
```

And this is how I send request to api:

```
  postWithApiUrl<T>(url: string, body: T): Promise<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(url, body, { headers }).subscribe(response => {
         resolve(response);
      });
    });
  }
```

And I use this returned promise like this;

```
this.postWithApiUrl(url, this.req).then(response => {
      console.log(response);      
    });
```

This is how I receive the response:

[image: console]

Where am I making the mistake at?

Comment: THat's not how `HttpResponseMessage` is used. It's not even needed if you simply want to return a file. `return File(package.GetAsByteArray(),"the-content-type")` is enough

Comment: BTW there are a lot of duplicates that show how to return an Excel file using EPPlus

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return a generated XLSX using (Core 2.2) Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468979/how-do-i-return-a-generated-xlsx-using-core-2-2-web-api)

Comment: it didn't really work for me. returning `File` seems like not an option in my project, it gives error.

Comment: What kind of project are you building? ASP.NET Core Web API does have a `File` method. Are you [mixing up the Web API versions perhaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460198/return-file-in-asp-net-core-web-api) ?