# Simple download file asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I want simply to go to `www.mywebsite.com/SomeController` and to download file located in my `wwwroot` folder with name `myApp.apk`

I have searched so many question and neither of them explains how to do it. All are complex and doesn't involve direct download like this.

So i have controller with index function and i need to return file download.

```
 public IActionResult Index() {
    return DownnloadMyFile("/myApp.apk");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return file in ASP.Net Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460198/return-file-in-asp-net-core-web-api)

Comment: [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: Specify, you have ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core? MVC or WebAPI?