# Asynchronously Streaming Video with .Net Core API from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, html5-video, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-blob-storage

I have found a bunch of examples that use objects not available to me within my application and don't seem to match up to my version of .NET Core web API. In essence, I am working on a project that will have  tags on a web page and want to load the videos using a stream from the server rather than directly serving the files via a path. One reason is the source of the files may change and serving them via path isn't what my customer wants. So I need to be able to open a stream and async write the video file.

This for some reason produces JSON data so that's wrong. I am downloading the video file from Azure Blob storage and returning as a stream, but I just don't understand what I need to do to send a streamed video file to a  tag in HTML.

My API Controller,

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("getintroductoryvideos")]
    public async Task<Stream> GetIntroductoryVideos()
    {
        try
        {
            return  _documentsService.WriteContentToStream().Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

My Service class,

```
 public async Task<Stream> WriteContentToStream()
    {
        var cloudBlob = await _blobService.GetBlobAsync(PlatformServiceConstants._blobIntroductoryVideoContainerPath + PlatformServiceConstants.IntroductoryVideo1, introductoryvideocontainerName);
        await cloudBlob.FetchAttributesAsync();

        var fileStream = new MemoryStream();
        await cloudBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream);
        return fileStream;
    }
```

Comment: what is this _blobService?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the code below:

API Controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("getintroductoryvideos")]
public async Task<FileContentResult> GetIntroductoryVideos(string videoname)
{        
   return  await _documentsService.WriteContentToStream();        
}
```

Service class:

```
public async Task<FileContentResult> WriteContentToStream()
{
    var cloudBlob = await _blobService.GetBlobAsync(PlatformServiceConstants._blobIntroductoryVideoContainerPath + PlatformServiceConstants.IntroductoryVideo1, introductoryvideocontainerName);

    MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream();
    await cloudBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream);
    return new FileContentResult (fileStream.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream");

}
```

Html:

```
<div className="xxx">
  <video height="auto">
      <source src="xx/getintroductoryvideos?videoname=xxx" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Small update that, we need to enable the "RangeProcessing"  (i.e)   var result = new FileContentResult(memStream.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream");
                result.EnableRangeProcessing = true;

Comment: what is this _blobService?

Comment: _BlobService is my service class where you are inheriting the actual blob container of Azure

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to avoid loading the entire video in memory before returning it. You should be able to pass through a stream by using `FileStreamResult`:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("getintroductoryvideos")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetIntroductoryVideos()
{
  var cloudBlob = await _blobService.GetBlobAsync(PlatformServiceConstants._blobIntroductoryVideoContainerPath + PlatformServiceConstants.IntroductoryVideo1, introductoryvideocontainerName);
  var stream = await cloudBlob.OpenReadAsync();
  return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

Comment: This function also working fine but not able to forward the video. And a little slow. I think we need to enable Http Range.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have done. The key point is the last line. The last parameter there enables the range request called **EnableRangeProcessing**. Although this starts supporting from .net core 2.1 and 2.1 plus.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("getintroductoryvideos")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetIntroductoryVideos()
{
  var cloudBlob = await _blobService.GetBlobAsync(PlatformServiceConstants._blobIntroductoryVideoContainerPath + PlatformServiceConstants.IntroductoryVideo1, introductoryvideocontainerName);
  var stream = await cloudBlob.OpenReadAsync();
  return new File(stream, "application/octet-stream",true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in .NET 6 that supports streaming and forwarding/backwarding in the html video. In this way even if your video file is big you don't need to download all it in the back end before returning it to front end and is much faster

Controller: (note that File is from ControllerBase.File and so must be here)

```
[AllowAnonymous]    
[HttpGet("videoStream/{videoId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetVideoStream(string videoId)
    {
        (Stream stream, string contentType) =  await service.GetVideoStream(videoId);
        return File(stream, contentType, true); //important to set it to true to support forwarding/backwarding
    }
```

In the service or where you want:

```
public async Task<(Stream, string)> GetVideoStream(string videoName)
{
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = BlobService.GetBlobContainerClient("YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME");
        BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(videoName);
        var properties = await blobClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
        string contentType = properties.Value.ContentType;
        Stream stream = await blobClient.OpenReadAsync();
        return (stream, contentType);

}
```

HTML:

```
<video controls>
   <source src="YOUR_BASE_URL/videostream/YOUR_FILE_NAME" type="video/mp4" />

  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>
```