# stream video from AzureBlob in Blazor component Web Server c#

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming, blazor-server-side

I am working on a feature where I want to stream video from azure blob .video files are already uploaded to azureBlob, I can use the blob URI but my blobs are compressed so I cant stream video directly from the Blob URI. for that reason I fetch the blob from the azure storage, Decompressed it and got the actual memory stream of a video. Now I want to play the video from that stream.
I researched out and find out that from JS it can be achieved. but I don't want to use js snippet to run this. is there any balzor web component from which I can achieve this. I have also tried to used blazored.video library from Nuget but still I didn't find that much helpful.

```
@using Blazored.Video
@using Blazored.Video.Support


@if (File != null)
{
    <BlazoredVideo class="w-100"
                   style="max-width:800px;"
                   controls="controls">
        <source src="@File.FileUri" type="video/mp4" />
    </BlazoredVideo>
}
```

Comment: I'm curious also.  I currently use the JS player sample from the Azure sample page, which I'm not a big fan of anyway.

Comment: can you please share the link with me for what you use.  @Bennyboy1973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to achieve this It simply requires me to create a web API that returns the content stream of my video.

I follow this example to handle streaming in my Web API

[Asynchronously Streaming Video with .Net Core API from Azure Blob Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61803684/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-net-core-api-from-azure-blob-storage)

My work

Page.razor

```
<BlazoredVideo class="w-100"
               style="max-width:800px;"
               controls="controls">
    <source src="api/Blob/PlayVideo" type="video/mp4" />
</BlazoredVideo>
```

API Endpoint

```
 [HttpGet("api/Blob/PlayVideo")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AnonymousPlayVideoAsync()
        {               
                var cloudBlob = await _azureBlobStorageService.RetrieveBlobiAsync("Test.mp4");
          
             var stream = new MemoryStream();
            await cloudBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);

            //.. Decompression of Stream comes here

            var result= new FileContentResult(stream.ToArray(), "video/mp4");
            result.EnableRangeProcessing = true;           
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: You probably want to avoid loading the entire video in memory before returning it. You should be able to pass through a stream by using `FileStreamResult`