# How to return images via Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I get the '414 (Request-URI Too Long)' error when returning my image as a Base64 encoded string via the web api.

I currently have the following Action in my Web API Controller:

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("GetAllEvents")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Event>> Get()
{
    var vm = EventsViewModel.NewInstance;
    return await vm.GetAllEvents();
}
```

And the vm.GetAllEvents() code:

```
public async Task<List<Event>> GetAllEvents()
    {
        var result = await DataStore.SelectAll();

        result.ForEach(x =>
        {
            var byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(x.ThumbnailPath);
            x.ThumbnailEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
        });

        return result;
    }
```

I consume the WebAPI action as follow:

```
this.ajaxRetrieve = function(url, data, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(result) {
            onSuccessCallback(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            onErrorCallback(xhr, status, error);
        }
    });
}
```

What would be the better approach to take, to avoid this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i strongly suggest to you use stream instead of Base64String. its efficient and fast. here you can find the good example:
[Returning binary file from controller in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api)

**UPDATE**
but you cant return array of streams with web api. so alternative option is byte array. something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<List<byte[]>> Get()
{
    var files= await GetAllEvents();

    return files;
}
```

And the `GetAllEvents()` code:

```
public async Task<List<byte[]>> GetAllEvents()
{
    var list = new List<byte[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var byteArray = await Task.Run(() => System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"filePath"));
        list.Add(byteArray);
    }
    return list;
}
```

hope this could solve your problem.

Comment: With this example, should I create a separate Action in the controller for only returning the image??

Comment: that's clear. return HttpResponseMessage instead of Task<IEnumerable<Event>>. then just read the file as stream and return it just like the sample code.

Comment: These solutions don't work for me, I get the following:  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: my bad. after little googling i found out you cant have array of streams as your web api output. i updated my answer. hope this could solve your problem.