# How do I save a blob response type in Angular 4+

Tags: javascript, angular, file, typescript, save

So I am calling an API, which returns to my Angular a file, like so:

```
getFile(fileInformation) {
  const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'filedownload', fileInformation, { reportProgress: true, responseType: "blob" });
  return this.http.request(req);
}
```

And in the API Controller (I followed [this SO top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api) to figure this step out):

```
Public Function GetFile(fileInformation As FileDto) As HttpResponseMessage
    Dim filePath = Path.Combine(FileConstants.FilePath, fileInformation.FileType, fileInformation.FileName)
    Dim fileStream = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    Dim result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    result.Content = New StreamContent(fileStream)
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream")

    Return result
End Function
```

The returned result from this call is of `HttpResponse`, and the body is of type `Blob`.

```
HttpResponse: {
  blob: {
    size: 289940,
    type: "application/octet-stream"
  },
  headers: ...,
  status: 200,
  ...
}
```

How do I now trigger a download for this file in the Angular component where I receive the response?

Comment: in Angular2 (4) I simply installed FileSaver and then imported it into my class and then ran `FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName);`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

install [FileSaver from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver).

```bash
npm install --save file-saver
```

import it into your class where you have the blob instance

```js
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
```

Then just call

```js
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName);
```

Comment: You saved me a lot of ugly code with this package. Thanks!

Comment: This package saved me a lot of ugly code, as well. :D

Comment: For Angular 10 there is warning: "CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts." due to using file-saver.

Comment: @GregorAlbert Oh no! A warning? What a nightmare!

Answer (score 5):

As @Jason Spradlin pointed out you can use  [FileSaver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) package

There is another package to [save file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@progress/kendo-file-saver) :

```
npm install @progress/kendo-file-saver --save
```

**Usage:**

```
import { saveAs } from '@progress/kendo-file-saver'

saveAs(data: string | Blob, fileName: string, options?: SaveOptions)
```

#### 1-Data is base64

```
const result = `data:${YOUR_MIME_TYPE};base64,` + YOUR_DATA;
saveAs(result, YOUR_FILE_NAME);
```

#### 2-Data is Blob

```
saveAs(YOUR_DATA, YOUR_FILE_NAME);
```

**Manually**:

```
const file = new window.Blob([data], { type: contentType });

const downloadAncher = document.createElement("a");
downloadAncher.style.display = "none";

const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
downloadAncher.href = fileURL;
downloadAncher.download = fileName;
downloadAncher.click();
```

Comment: Will new window trigger popup blockers? (in 'manually' code). (Also: it's anchor with an o =P)