# how to get image file from web-api?

Tags: sql-server, angular, asp.net-web-api

I`m working on my project that uses sql as data base  and asp.net web-api with entity framework.
I uploaded into the sql table image as varbinary(MAX) and then converted it into image in the web-api.
now how can I get that image with angular 8 ?

The get method:

```
  [Route("api/images/{ID}")]
        public Image GetImage(int ID)
        {
            var selectedimg = db.imges.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id ==ID); 
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(selectedimg.pic);
            Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            return returnImage;

        }
```

ts component:

```
constructor(private http:HttpClient ) {
}  
image:any;
ngOnInit(){
this.http.get("https://localhost:44355/api/images/1").subscribe(data=>this.image=data);
};
```

html:

```
<img  [src]="image" >
```

Comment: Just output the data from the database. Any server side image objects won’t do anything here.

Comment: and how do i do that ?

Comment: This may be of use https://stackoverflow.com/q/9541351/1806780