# .net/swagger resposne type Blob

Tags: .net, angular, swagger

Is it possible to set in the c# controller response type Blob ?
I automatically generate a client from swagger, and I want to return a blob to preview the pdf.

Angular

```
var f = new Blob([response], type: 'application/pdf'});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(f);
window.open(url);
```

c#

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(???), 200)]
[Procudes("application/pdf")
```

locally it works but on the server I have an error: *http failure during parsing for ...*

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got something similar to facilitate file downloads through the API. I use the [`ControllerBase.File()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-7.0) helper which returns a [`FileStreamResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filestreamresult?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

As such I use `Type = typeof(FileResult)`.

```cs
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(FileResult))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Type = typeof(BadRequestResult))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound, Type = typeof(NotFoundResult))]
```