How to respond to requests coming from img html tag?
I am trying to write an endpoint in ASP.NET Core to respond to img src tags to display the image without fetching the image data manually. I save the uploaded images as is. Now I want to create an endpoint in ASP.NET Core to act as if src link is a file.
I put this into my src attribute:
http://localhost:4000/api/ecm/GetImage?imageID=a7a0cc09-474e-4e7e-9dd0-d23c867f9e4a

And this is the code of the GetImage method:
[HttpGet]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
[Produces("image/jpg", "image/png", "image/webp")]
public Binary GetImage([FromQuery] string imageID)
{
    return (service.GetImage(imageID));
}

But the request throws an error "http 406 (not acceptable)".
What is the correct way to do this?
Edit: The Accept header of browser request:
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd```


if you examine the "accept" request headers produced by your browser, with a tool like Postman, could you please dump them in the question?

can you try return a File instead of Binary? see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/54298794/479251

@Pac0 I added the Accept header. As you can see it accepts multiple formats like webp and I have included it in the Produces attribe and I think it should be enough. I don't know what is the problem here. I save the image data on the database not in a file so I think I can't use File as return type.

I used FileContentResult:
[HttpGet]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
[Produces("image/jpg", "image/png", "image/webp")]
public IActionResult GetImage([FromQuery] string imageID)
{
    byte[] imageData = service.GetImage(imageID).ToArray();
    if (imageData == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return new FileContentResult(imageData, "image/jpeg");
}

